# WooCommerce checkout payment options fail

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

Billing details & payment options on my checkout page fail to load.
They appear behind the loader spinner, then they're all removed and replaced by "**-1**"...

Already asked a lot to Google but I didn't find someone who had this issue.

- I checked the WooCommerce status page and just increased the WP Memory Limit to 64Mo as advised.
- I updated the plugin but nothing changed.
- I tried to disable PayPal option, and just enable basic payment options (bank transfer, check, ...)
- No errors displayed (WP_DEBUG = true)
- No errors in JS console
- Nothing about in PHP log...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally found out.
It seems that the issue is :

I manually delete the Cookie via Chrome Web Tools, because I'm working on URL referer tracking.
So I'm logged in to my WP dashboard in one tab, and obviously disconnected on my checkout page (in a 2nd tab) because the site cookie has been deleted.

It seems like this is confusing the whole thing. If I log out from WP admin and refresh the checkout page, it works.